# Running pipeline in AzureDevops gets 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-artifacts

We have both pipeline and artifact under the same project. We set the role for '[project-name] Build Service ([company-name])' to 'Contributor' in Feed Settings > Permissions, following the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#pipelines-permissions

When we run the pipeline we get the following error message:

`Failed to read artifact descriptor for [package-name]: Could not transfer artifact [package-name] from/to [feed-name] ([feed-url]): authentication failed for [package-url], status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]`

Is there any other way to give the right to pipeline to access packages in the feed/artifact?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to check with the following things to resolve the issue:

1. On the **Feed Settings** > **Permissions** page, ensure you have granted the following two identities with the required permissions.

   - **`{Project-Name} Build Service ({Organization-Name})`**
   - **`Project Collection Build Service ({Organization-Name})`**
2. Try to re-create a new pipeline with the same definition.
3. In the pipeline, try to use the associated authenticate task, such as [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines), [NuGet authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines), etc...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did all those steps that you suggested. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Amargi, How about try to re-configure you project with the packages following the steps of "**Connect to feed**"?